# Why does is happen in eclipse that a JNI error has occured?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I try to execute a program in Eclipse Mars, It says something like :

"A JNI error has occured. Please check your installation."

Here is my code :

```
package java.john.rex.sample.palindrome
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String a, b = "";
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the string you want to check:");
        a = s.nextLine();
        int n = a.length();
        for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            b = b + a.charAt(i);
        }
        if(a.equalsIgnoreCase(b))
        {
            System.out.println("The string is palindrome.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The string is not palindrome.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is caused by this line.

```
package java.john.rex.sample.palindrome
```

Java may not be used as a packagename. A package name may contain the word java (for instance `package javaName.john.rex.sample.palindrome;` but it may not be the complete name for a package, which is why your package naming is causing this problem.

Remove it and then try again.

Comment: who says that's not correct? have you seen the OP's project structure? Though you're probably right. adding that in front of a correct package declaration could lead to that issue.

Comment: @Stultuske But this is eactly the reason. I just tested it. Changing the package and moving the java file into the appropriate directory lets the program execute without errors. Correct answer!

Comment: Indeed. a shame IDE's don't pick up on issues like this before compilation.

Comment: @Jyotirmay Your point is correct, your explanation is wrong (due to badly worded). It is correct to include the word java in a package name, it's when Java is the package name, that it fails.